# Finding the limit of a function $f(x,y)$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

How can I prove that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{y^{3}}{\sqrt{x}(x^{2}+y^{2})}=0\,?$$

I can't use polar coordinates because $\frac{\rho^{1/2}\sin^{3}(\theta)}{\cos^{1/2}(\theta)}$ is not bounded. But I don't understand how can I bound this limit. Any hint?

Comment: The hint is: the limit doesn't equal $0$! And your calculation is halfway to proving that. (Note that you should have $\rho^{3/2}$, not $\rho^3$, in the numerator.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that along the sequence $\left(\frac{1}{n^6}, \frac{1}{n}\right)$ the function evaluates to

$$
\frac{\frac{1}{n^3}}{\frac{1}{n^3}\left(\frac{1}{n^{12}}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}
= \left(\frac{1}{n^{12}}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{-1},
$$

which does not converge as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Thank you! This sequence will be useful. May I ask you why Wolfram Tool for double limits tells me that the limit converge ? Is it unreliable?

Comment: @GiacomoGatti I don't know, but it certainly is unreliable enough to get this limit wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)